# C# record types as discriminated unions vs. third party libraries

Tags: c#, .net, record, api-design, discriminated-union

In a project, I'm trying to implement discriminated unions using records to move away from throwing exceptions to handle "expected" errors at the application layer. It seemed an overkill to add a third party library so I tried rolling my own and ended with something along the lines of this record:

```cs
public abstract record CreateCustomerResponse
{
    private CreateCustomerResponse() { }

    public sealed record Success(Customer Customer) : CreateCustomerResponse;

    public sealed record Error(string Code, string Message) : CreateCustomerResponse, IErrorResponse;

    public sealed record Unauthorized() : CreateCustomerResponse;
}
```

Which is basically an abstract record that cannot be inherited except for its child records, which are in turn sealed, limiting the resulting types that you can have.

It can be implemented not very differently from how you would any other DU using a library:

```cs
static CreateCustomerResponse CreateCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    // Or do data validation however you prefer.
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.FirstName))
        return new CreateCustomerResponse.Error(nameof(customer.FirstName), "First name is required");

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.LastName))
        return new CreateCustomerResponse.Error(nameof(customer.LastName), "Last name is required");

    return new CreateCustomerResponse.Success(customer);
}
```

And it can be consumed/transformed as needed using newer C# features such as pattern matching very easily:

```cs
static string PrintResponse(CreateCustomerResponse response)
{
    return response switch
    {
        CreateCustomerResponse.Success result => $"OK, so {result.Customer.FirstName} was created",
        CreateCustomerResponse.Error => $"Sorry, operation failed: {response}",
        CreateCustomerResponse.Unauthorized => "You're unauthorized pal",
        _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
    };
}
```

I've seen many people using third party libraries (*OneOf* and others) to accomplish something similar, but it seems simple enough not to need a library for this use case; and it even allows the use of pattern matching, so you don't need a "Match" method or such to deal with the result.

Only issue I have found is that the `switch` expression believes not all cases are covered (which is not true) if the `_` pattern is not included, but adding it does not harm. And yet I see same benefits: you are forced to check for the actual result in order to use it and are bound to a known set of options.

**So the question is this:**

Are there any visible shortcomings in this implementation that I may not be taking into consideration? Is there anything I'm missing by not using a known third party library in this context, which seems to be generally accepted?

Community input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

A major shortcoming here is that these are classes. Every result now involves heap allocations *and* type testing. That poor garbage collector!

A struct record might work better here, perhaps with some simple accessors to check for the outcome (which could be via booleans or an enum).

Of course that still leaves lots of branches in *every* outcome, rather than letting the success case run branch-free, and only having fault handling in the failure cases (which are presumably rarer). You'll still usually need exception handling, as these aren't the only way things can fail, so you've added lots of branching while not removing any fault handling.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of using OneOf for example is the compile-time check that every possible value of the union is being handled.

With your implementation, if you add another possible value for `CreateCustomerResponse`, there is nothing that will stop you from building and running your program without changing your switch expression and you might end up throwing the `NotImplementedException` because you forgot to handle it there.

With OneOf, you would not even be able to build the solution in the first place without handling the value you just added to the record.